# Google analytics API is really slow

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I have a small function that gets the page- and visitor count from Google Analytics for each URL in an array.

```
$filter_path = $my_url;
$filter = 'pagePath =@ ' . $filter_path;
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('pagePath'),array('pageviews','visitors'),'',$filter,'2010-01-01',date('Y-m-d'));

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result) {
  $pageviews = $result->getPageviews();
  $visits = $result->getVisitors();
}
```

This works, but 10 URLs takes about 1-2 minutes to process. When i want to process 100 urls it takes about 15 minutes...

Does anyone have any idea of how/if you could make this query faster?

Comment: This sucks. In our experience, it's 30 seconds every time no matter what, just awful.

Answer (score 1):

THere are some rate limits in place https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas aren't you reaching them?

Comment: No i´m not reaching them :/ I have increased the limits in Google API Console too.